# 99 names of Allah

Tags: asma-ul-husna

Is it ok to name a person Muhaimin or is that shirk because Muhaimin is 1 of the 99 names of Allah?
My name is Muhaiminul Islam Chowdhury but in school they just call me 'Muhaiminul' and I never tell them not to call me that. Do I get sins for that? I heard that it is ok for a person to be called 'Muhaiminul Islam' but not 'Muhaiminul.' Is that true?

Comment: See http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2207/18