# Naming a company after one of the (99) names of Allah

Tags: halal-haram, naming

I'm going to start logistics company.

My question is: I'm trying to use one the Great names of Allah (swt) to my company. I'm using Al-jaleel name its means The Mighty. So using this name to my company is halal or haram. My company name is (Mighty Shipping pvt ltd).

Kindly suggest is my future.

Comment: What make you think that this shouldn't be allowed? This post is relevant to some extent http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/is-naming-a-person-using-one-of-allahs-names-allowed?rq=1

Comment: We seek effortful questions showing prior research.  Asking about permissibility without indicating a reason it's not the [default ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36838) is considered [off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663).  Please [edit] the question accordingly.