# Is it haram to name a women by Allah's name?

Tags: sahih-muslim

Is it haram to name a woman Allah? This women's name is Allah Rakhe, and I don't know if it is haram or not. Doesn't Allah's name mean ''Creator of the universe''?

Comment: well the name means creator of the universe

Comment: For such a query you need to consult a Mufti who is familiar with your language. If I am correct "Allah rakhe" means 'One protected by Allah', its a compound name like Abdullah.

Answer (score 1):

It's forbidden.
It is discussed which of the attributive 99 names are allowed, see [Is naming a person using one of Allah's names allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/is-naming-a-person-using-one-of-allahs-names-allowed)

In this discussion, an undisputed consent among all schools and all scholars is that humans must not be named Allah; understood as a proper Name of God, it is reserved to Him, and understood from the origin of the word, "The God", it can be understood directly.

Answer (score 0):

Salam. I have heard of this name twice before here in Pakistan and to the best of my knowledge, It means "Protected by Allah" in Urdu (and possibly Persian as well).

So in that case, it would be Halal.